# Can´t reproduce bootstrap documentation using js example. Why?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I´m trying to reproduce bootstrap documentation example:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior

With 2 diferences: using js to create the html tags and using a nested list instead of single list.

The 'activate' highlight doesn´t work and the right side content doesn´t change. Need help on why and how to make it work.

I´m also trying to create a collapse effect for the nested list when the parent item is clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
</head>
<body>

    <div id="tree"></div>
    
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        
        function clearChildren(node){

            while(node.children.length > 0)
                node.removeChild(node.lastElementChild)
        }

        let idCounter = 0

        function createNode(name,meta={}){

          return {
              name,
              id: idCounter++,
              children:new Array(),
              meta
          }
        }

        function makeTreeTable(parentElement, rootNode){

            clearChildren(parentElement)
        
            parentElement.setAttribute('class', 'row')

            //Make Tree Div
            const divTree = document.createElement('div')
            divTree.setAttribute('class','col-8')
            divTree.setAttribute('id', 'div-tree')
            parentElement.appendChild(divTree)

            //Make Meta Div
            const divMeta = document.createElement('div')
            divMeta.setAttribute('class','col-4')
            divMeta.setAttribute('id', 'div-node')
            parentElement.appendChild(divMeta)

            
            const metaDisplay = document.createElement('div')
            metaDisplay.setAttribute('class','tab-content')
            metaDisplay.setAttribute('id','nav-tabContent')
            divMeta.appendChild(metaDisplay)

            maketree(divTree, rootNode, metaDisplay)
        }

        let activeMeta = 'tab-pane fade show active'
        function createMetaList(treeNode){
            
            const metaList = document.createElement('div')
            console.log(treeNode.id)
            metaList.setAttribute('id', `${treeNode.id}-meta`)
            metaList.setAttribute('class',activeMeta)
            activeMeta = 'tab-pane fade'
            metaList.setAttribute('role','tabpanel')
            metaList.setAttribute('aria-labelledby',treeNode.id)

            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(treeNode.meta)) {
                const metaItem = document.createElement('div')
                metaItem.innerHTML = `${key} : ${value}`
                metaList.appendChild(metaItem)
            }
            return metaList
        }

        let activeNode = 'list-group-item list-group-item-action active'
        function maketree(parentElement, nodeTgt, metaDisplay) {
        
            //Make ul node
          const ul = document.createElement("div");
          ul.setAttribute('class', 'list-group')
          ul.setAttribute('id','nodeTgt.name')
          ul.setAttribute('role','tablist')

            //Make all li´s nodes
          for(const node of nodeTgt.children){

              const li = document.createElement("a");
              li.innerHTML = node.name;
              li.setAttribute("id", node.id);
              li.setAttribute("class", activeNode)
              activeNode = 'list-group-item list-group-item-action'
              li.setAttribute('data-bs-toogle','list')
              li.setAttribute('role','tab')
              li.setAttribute('href',`#${node.id}-meta`)
              li.setAttribute('aria-controls',`${node.id}-meta`)

              li.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                  e.stopPropagation()
                  console.log('clicked ', node.name)
                })

              ul.appendChild(li);
              metaDisplay.appendChild(createMetaList(node))

              //Make recursive items
              if(nodeTgt.children.length > 0)         
                  maketree(li,node, metaDisplay)
          }
          parentElement.appendChild(ul)
        }

        function makeMeta(i){
            return{
                meta1:`this is ${i}`,
                meta2:`this is ${++i}`,
                meta3:`this is ${++i}`,
            }
        }
        const root = createNode('root', makeMeta(0))
        root.children.push(createNode('node1', makeMeta(1)))
        root.children.push(createNode('node2', makeMeta(2)))
        root.children.push(createNode('node3', makeMeta(3)))

        const node1 = root.children[0]
        const node2 = root.children[1]
        const node3 = root.children[2]

        node1.children.push(createNode('node11', makeMeta(11)))
        node1.children.push(createNode('node12', makeMeta(12)))
        
        node2.children.push(createNode('node21', makeMeta(21)))
        node2.children.push(createNode('node22', makeMeta(22)))

        node3.children.push(createNode('node31', makeMeta(31)))
        node3.children.push(createNode('node32', makeMeta(32)))

        const node11 = node1.children[0]
        const node12 = node1.children[1]
        const node31 = node3.children[0]
        const node32 = node3.children[1]

        node11.children.push(createNode('node111', makeMeta(111)))
        node11.children.push(createNode('node112', makeMeta(112)))
        node12.children.push(createNode('node121', makeMeta(121)))
        node12.children.push(createNode('node122', makeMeta(122)))

        node31.children.push(createNode('node311', makeMeta(111)))
        node31.children.push(createNode('node312', makeMeta(112)))
        node32.children.push(createNode('node321', makeMeta(121)))
        node32.children.push(createNode('node322', makeMeta(122)))

        makeTreeTable(document.querySelector('#tree'), root)
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the created elements individually.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/list-group/#via-javascript

Put the following at the end of your script:

```js
    const triggerTabList = document.querySelectorAll('#tree a')
    triggerTabList.forEach(triggerEl => {
      const tabTrigger = new bootstrap.Tab(triggerEl)

      triggerEl.addEventListener('click', event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        tabTrigger.show()
      })
    })
```

Then you will see an error that says `"#1-meta" is not a valid selector`. I think you need to refactor your code to have all of the `id`s start with a letter [a-z]. So you want to use `"meta-1"` format instead.